# How to enable root password in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, password, sudo

Whenever I use the sudo su command to work as root, it does not ask my root password. How can I make it prompt for root password?

Comment: Not required and not recommended. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: That just changes the root users password. The OP wants to be prompted for their password. Do you have a password for your account

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, set up a password for root, for example with `sudo passwd`. Then turn on a flag in `/etc/sudoers` file by running `sudo visudo` and adding the line:

```
Defaults        rootpw
```

(If you haven't modified the sudoers file before, you can put it next to the other Defaults clauses.)

Before committing to this specific setting, please consult `man 5 sudoers`, specifically the options `rootpw`, `runaspw` and `targetpw`.

Also, please note that this does not seem to be an encouraged configuration of an ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sudo` will never ask for the root password. It will only ever ask for your password. That's the whole point of how it works.

You can set the password for the `root` user, but `sudo su` will never ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple answer but here I go,

1. Open Terminal
2. Type sudo -i
3. Enter your root password
4. Type passwd
5. You can now login as root

Ubuntu's Unity does not seem to like a direct root login and it's very insecure to leave the account unlocked like this...

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: Open terminal
Step 2: Type passwd
Step 3: Set your Unix password e.g.(abcdefg)